# Can TextMate show tab vs space characters?

Tags: textmate

Using TextMate on Mac, the "invisibles" can be displayed by using

```
View -> Show Invisibles
```

But the space vs tab characters are not shown, and Preferences doesn't seem to have any entry to change that either.  Is there a way to show them?  It is because some older coder may have tab or space mixed together so what looks good in the editor may actually be misaligned. (editor shows tab as 2 spaces)

Answer (score 10):

Tab characters are shown, but spaces are not.  What's probably happening is that you have Soft tabs turned on, in which case the tabs are converted into spaces automatically.

[alt text http://grab.by/grabs/fabaea391dc8bc764636f0ca19a8c38d.png](http://grab.by/grabs/fabaea391dc8bc764636f0ca19a8c38d.png)

In this picture there is a tab character, new line, tab character, new line, soft tab, new line

See [this thread](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2006-March/009262.html) for an explanation as to why spaces are not shown.

Here is where you can change soft/real tabs.
[alt text http://grab.by/grabs/783db3a88609a01c7702cbd250f495c6.png](http://grab.by/grabs/783db3a88609a01c7702cbd250f495c6.png)

Comment: so when "Soft Tabs" is on, then tabs are not shown as well?  So to see them, choose the "Show Invisible" and also disable "Soft Tabs"?

Comment: Soft tabs literally means that the tabs are converted into the equivalent number of spaces.  So you won't see the tab character.  If all you need to do is distinguish between tabs and spaces, then you're fine leaving it on or off - you'll be able to tell the difference either way

Comment: actually, i think it might have been a tab character that was there...  and I think TextMate won't convert existing tab character into spaces, only new ones.

Comment: You can select a section of text, right click, choose Convert -> and then Tabs to Spaces.

Comment: Was trying to turn on soft tabs for ages until i saw your screen shot... the control is at the bottom of the page to turn it on (not using shell variables as stated on another thread)

Answer (score 1):

If "Show invisibles" is activated, you will see a little triangle for each tab, which points to the right. Spaces are not shown at all, you can only see them indirectly, i.e. via the symbol which represents the line break. If the line break isn't the first character after your code of that line, there are spaces in between.

So to make a long answer short: You should already see tabs, however the symbols representing the invisibles are sometimes hard to see.